# Hide iOS nav bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My program uses

`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];   //it hides
    }`

to hide a navigation controller and

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`{
}

to describe a AVFoundation camera method. I get a warning for using the same method names. Is there another naming convention i can set to use both methods in my app?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where di AVFoundation come into it? Can you show the warning (i.e. Copy paste it). Also maybe some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you hide the `Navigation Bar` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: no; right under implementation and right before view did load

Comment: I don't get you. You are not gonna set `setNavigationBarHidden` every time the view shows up right. You're only gonna do it when the view first came up. So put it in viewDidLoad. And your questions is very unclear